# How to fix ''failed to load ldlinux.c32'' error while booting Ubuntu 20.04 LTS version?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, bios

**Failed to load ldlinux.c32**

I burned my USB stick (16GB) as a bootable device by using Rufus. Before burning, Rufus asked me to download one file. I downloaded it.  After that normal burning process.
My setting are
Partition scheme **MBR**
Target system **BIOS or UEFI**
File system **FAT32**
I burned
**Ubuntu 20.04.3 desktop amd64.iso** file.
After burning,  I inserted USB stick to my target pc and Press F9 to boot device option.
Choice my USB device.
Then this error appear.
I tried this process again and again.
My target laptop stcuk in blue screen restart loop.
Please help me.

Comment: check this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/985612/running-ubuntu-from-a-usb-failed-to-load-ldlinux-c32

Answer (score 0):

Update your BIOS or Format your flash disk to FAT/ FAT 16 not the difault FAT 32 from Rufus, I presume you using an older version of BIOS.